# AES-256-CBC encrypted with PHP and decrypt in Java

Tags: java, php, security, encryption, cryptography

I am in a situation where a JSON is encrypted in PHP's `openssl_encrypt` and needs to be decrypted in JAVA.

```
$encrypted = "...ENCRYPTED DATA...";
$secretFile = "/path/to/secret/saved/in/text_file";
$secret = base64_decode(file_get_contents($secretFile));
var_dump(strlen($secret)); // prints : int(370)

$iv = substr($encrypted, 0, 16);
$data = substr($encrypted, 16);
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($data, "aes-256-cbc", $secret, null, $iv);
```

This `$decrypted` has correct data which is now decrypted.

Now, the problem is when I try to do same things in Java it doesn't work :(

```
String path = "/path/to/secret/saved/in/text";
String payload = "...ENCRYPTED DATA...";
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

String iv = payload.substring(0, 16);
byte[] secret = Base64.getDecoder().decode(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)));
String data = payload.substring(16);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secret, "AES");
IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes(), 0, cipher.getBlockSize());
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec); // This line throws exception : 

cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Here it is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 370 bytes
at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCrypt.init(AESCrypt.java:87)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherBlockChaining.init(CipherBlockChaining.java:91)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.init(CipherCore.java:591)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineInit(AESCipher.java:346)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1394)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1327)
at com.sample.App.main(App.java:70)
```

I have already visited similar question like

[AES-256 CBC encrypt in php and decrypt in Java or vice-versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42396690/aes-256-cbc-encrypt-in-php-and-decrypt-in-java-or-vice-versa)

[openssl_encrypt 256 CBC raw_data in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44259188/openssl-encrypt-256-cbc-raw-data-in-java)

[Unable to exchange data encrypted with AES-256 between Java and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537099/unable-to-exchange-data-encrypted-with-aes-256-between-java-and-php)

and list continues.... but no luck there

btw, this is how encryption is done in PHP

```
$secretFile = "/path/to/secret/saved/in/text_file";
$secret = base64_decode(file_get_contents($secretFile));
$iv = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8));
$enc = openssl_encrypt($plainText, "aes-256-cbc", $secret, false, $iv);
return $iv.$enc;
```

and yes, I forgot to mention that my JRE is already at `UnlimitedJCEPolicy` and I can't change PHP code.

I am totally stuck at this point and can't move forward. Please help out.

**EDIT#1**

```
byte[] payload = ....;
byte[] iv = ....;
byte[] secret = ....; // Now 370 bits
byte[] data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(payload);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(Arrays.copyOfRange(secret, 0, 32), "AES");
IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv, 0, cipher.getBlockSize());

cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
byte[] output = cipher.doFinal(data);

System.out.println(new String(output).trim());
```

Above snippet seems to be working with `openssl_encrypt`

**EDIT#2**

I am not sure if this is correct, but following is what I have done and encryption-decryption on both side are working fine.

Encrypt in PHP, Decrypt in JAVA use `AES/CBC/NoPadding`

Encrypt in JAVA, Decrypt in PHP use `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding`

Comment: Use a key with the correct length, for "aes-256" that is a 32-byte key.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a 370-byte AES key?

Comment: ^ Because key generation is not in my hand. It is done at PHP end and work perfectly there.

Comment: Don't forget to [authenticate your ciphertexts](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't provide a complete solution, but there are a few differences you should take care of

**Encoding:**

```
String iv = payload.substring(0, 16);
String data = payload.substring(16);
```

are you sure the IV and data are the same in Java and PHP (The IV is string?)? If the data are encrypted, they should be treated as a byte array, not string. Just REALLY make sure they are THE SAME (print hex/base64 in php and java)

For the IV you at the end call `iv.getBytes()`, but the locale encoding may/will corrupt your values. The String should be use only when it's really string (text). Don't use string for binaries.

Simply treat data and iv as byte[]

**Key generation according to the openssl**

<del>AES key must have length of 256 bit for `aes-256-cbc` used. The thing is - openssl by default doesn't use the provided secret as a key (I believe it can, but I don't know how it is to be specified in PHP).</del>

<del>see [OpenSSL EVP_BytesToKey issue in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47094518/openssl-evp-bytestokey-issue-in-java/47103931#47103931)</del>

and here is the EVP_BytesToKey implementation: https://olabini.com/blog/tag/evp_bytestokey/

<del>you should generate a 256 bit key usging the EVP_BytesToKey function (it's a key derivation function used by openssl).</del>

Edit:

Maarten (in the comments) is right. The *key* parameter is the key. Seems the PHP function is accepting parameter of any length which is misleading.  According to some articles (e.g. http://thefsb.tumblr.com/post/110749271235/using-opensslendecrypt-in-php-instead-of)  the key is trucated or padded to necessary length (so seems 370 bit key is truncated to length of 256 bits).

Comment: I agree with the first part. Simply stated, modern ciphers operate on bytes (or *octet strings*) not character strings. Anything done on textual strings in the question is **wrong**, especially in Java. In Java you need to operate on `byte[]`. Note that PHP **can** encode anything in a character string using escapes, so the ciphertext may be correct there... The second part doesn't seem to be correct if I look at the `openssl_encrypt` API description - I only see key and IV, no password and salt.

Comment: I have changed the implementation to `byte[]`. But yes, you guys are right somehow PHP is truncating this exceeded length to 256 bit. I did few changes and working now

Comment: Please check the updates. I think this is somehow misleading if keys are truncated by default in `openssl_en/decrypt`. 
This might be a silly question but what if 2 keys are having same initial 256 bits ?

Answer (score 1):

According to your example, I wrote fully working code for PHP and Java:
**AesCipher class:** https://gist.github.com/demisang/716250080d77a7f65e66f4e813e5a636

**Notes:**
-By default algo is AES-128-CBC.
-By default init vector is 16 bytes.
-Encoded result = base64(initVector + aes crypt).
-Encoded/Decoded results present as itself object, it gets more helpful and get possibility to check error, get error message and get init vector value after encode/decode operations.

**PHP:**

```
$secretKey = '26kozQaKwRuNJ24t';
$text = 'Some text'
$encrypted = AesCipher::encrypt($secretKey, $text);
$decrypted = AesCipher::decrypt($secretKey, $encrypted);

$encrypted->hasError(); // TRUE if operation failed, FALSE otherwise
$encrypted->getData(); // Encoded/Decoded result
$encrypted->getInitVector(); // Get used (random if encode) init vector
// $decrypted->* has identical methods
```

**JAVA:**

```
String secretKey = "26kozQaKwRuNJ24t";
String text = "Some text";

AesCipher encrypted = AesCipher.encrypt(secretKey, text);
AesCipher decrypted = AesCipher.decrypt(secretKey, encrypted);

encrypted.hasError(); // TRUE if operation failed, FALSE otherwise
encrypted.getData(); // Encoded/Decoded result
encrypted.getInitVector(); // Get used (random if encode) init vector
// decrypted.* has identical methods
```

Comment: You should add short explanation and then link to full solution